# Existence of Periodic Orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the planar system

$\dot x_1 = x_2 - x_1^3$

$\dot x_2 = -x_1$

Prove that there exists no periodic orbit in this system. I tried to use the Bendixson criteria. The divergence is equal to $-3x_1^2$ which is equal to zero on the $x_2$ axis and therefore we cannot use the Bendixson criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the system

$\dot x_1 = x_2 - x_1^3, \tag 1$

$\dot x_2 = -x_1, \tag 2$

we see that the divergence of the vector field $(x_2 - x_1^3, -x_1)^T$ is

$\dfrac{\partial (x_2 - x_1^3)}{\partial x_1} + \dfrac{\partial (-x_1)}{\partial x_2} = -3x_1^2; \tag 3$

since $-3x_1^2$ vanishes only on the set $\{(x_1, x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x_1 = 0 \}$, which being the $x_2$-axis is of measure $0$, and is negative everywhere else, it follows from [the Bendixson-Dulac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) that (1)-(2) has no periodic orbits.

Comment: The phase portrait using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7By+-+x%5E3,+-x%7D,+%7Bx,+-1,+1%7D,+%7By,+-1,+1%7D%5D)